# Grouping results of SELECT but keep some values unique

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a SQL table like this

```
year    tour     wins    cuts   money
1990     EUR       2         4    54,500
1990     USA       1         2    22,000
1991     EUR       4         2    154,000
1991     USA       2         1    245,000
and so on
```

I wish to GROUP the results by YEAR, summing up the wins and cuts
HOWEVER, I wish to keep the money column alone, and return both values, from each YEAR row, like moneyEUR and moneyUSA (based on the TOUR column)

I am currently doing a SELECT like this

```
SELECT year, SUM(wins), SUM(cuts), money FROM players GROUP BY year
```

This GROUPS fine by year, but just returns the first money value.

Is there a way I can also return each money value as separate values?
and still SUM up the other values per year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have always exactly 2 records for each year then you can do

```
SELECT year, 
       SUM(wins), 
       SUM(cuts), 
       sum(case when tour = 'EUR' then money end) as moneyEUR,
       sum(case when tour = 'USA' then money end) as moneyUSA
FROM players 
GROUP BY year
```

Comment: my apologies. i forgot a slight detail. I need to associate, or be able to tell, which row the money value came from, based on the tour column. (See the edited table description in the problem statement). So I need to know which tour value the money value is for. hence min or max doesn't work. Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.tour, t1.money, t1.year, t2.wins_sum, t2.cuts_sum
from players t1
join (
    select year
    sum(wins) wins_sum,
    sum(cuts) cuts_sum
    from players
    group by year
) t2 on t1.year = t2.year
```

Comment: THANK YOU for the quick response. How do I then access each money value with the answer? and can I associate which tour value row the money item came from?

Comment: @EdPattermann this query returns 1 row per money value. yes, you can add the tour to the select. see udpate

Comment: I see. Each row then has the same results, except the money value is different. Yes? I was hoping for one row per year, with summed values, and two money values, moneyEUR and moneyUSA. Appreciate the help. -- Ed

Comment: @EdPattermann that's correct. np, juergen's answer should provide what you're looking for then